# Calling gcloud with different service accounts in parallel and automatically using its project ID

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I know this has been asked many times because of the complete mess Google have made with authentication but I can't find an answer. I'm trying to create a CI pipeline that can use service account credentials from a file. I want to be able to run it locally or from a server. From what I've read gcloud inexplicably ignores the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var so I have to globally set my creds with the following, meaning I can kiss goodbye to any kind of parallelisation:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=$(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)
```

Surely it must be possible to run multiple commands in parallel with different SA credentials?

Also, the above approach ignores the project ID specified in the key file, so gcloud tries to target the last project ID I personally set for myself.

Is there a solution to this ridiculousness? I'm looking for a non-interactive, non-destructive (i.e. won't trash my personal creds) way of calling gcloud in parallel with different service accounts and automatically using their project IDs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it actually is possible with this:

```
    CLOUDSDK_AUTH_CREDENTIAL_FILE_OVERRIDE=$(GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_FILE) \
    CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT=$(GCP_PROJECT) \
    gcloud run deploy --allow-unauthenticated $(CLOUD_RUN_CONFIG) --image $(GCR_DOCKER_IMAGE)
```

It's a shame the docs are so poor it's taken me forever to find this info. Why gcloud doesn't just use the same env vars as all the libraries will remain a mystery to everyone outside Google...